# How to restart/reload VS Code host window on extension source code file changes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I'm developing a VS Code extension following the [vscode-extension-samples/helloworld-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/f1df8faee789ed72a42010a42e10bc9baf624929/helloworld-sample).

**Question:**

- Is there a way to Hot Module Replace or otherwise "patch" the source code loaded by the host window?
- Alternatively is there a way to reload the host window on source code changes?

---

When running the [`Run Extension`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/f1df8faee789ed72a42010a42e10bc9baf624929/helloworld-sample/.vscode/launch.json) launch configuration, `tsc` is executed in `--watch` mode watching for file changes and a new VS Code window is launched acting as the in-development-extension's host.

**Expectation:**

Updating the extentions's source code (e.g. [`extension.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/f1df8faee789ed72a42010a42e10bc9baf624929/helloworld-sample/src/extension.ts#L19)) updates the hosted extension's behaviour accordingly.

**Actual:**

Updating the extentions's source code dosn't have any effect in the hosted extension's behaviour.

**Notes:**

Updating the extentions's source code and then manually hitting `Ctrl + R` to reload the extension host window seems to "reload" the latest version of the extension's source code too, updating the hosted extension's behaviour as expected.

---

Here's  my current config source code:

```json
// launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "name": "Develop Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"],
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: dev",
      "postDebugTask": "Terminate All Tasks",
    },
  ]
}
```

```json
// tasks.json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "dev",
      "detail": "Launch extension for local development in a new (host) VS Code window.",
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": { "reveal": "always" },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true,
      },
      "icon": { "id": "tools" },
    },
    {
      "label": "Terminate All Tasks",
      "detail": "Stop all running tasks.", // e.g. useful for endless tasks like file watchers
      "command": "echo ${input:terminate}",
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "icon": { "id": "stop-circle" },
    },
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "terminate",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate",
      "args": "terminateAll",
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no automatic reload of the extension development host. You have to do it manually.

Comment: In the age of amazing dev tools like vite, I can't stop but think that surely we could do better than that...

Comment: VS Code is a very complex beast. It's not like HMR in a web app, where you just replace a couple of lines. Reloading means to restart all extensions, do internal management and whatnot. I fully understand why it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I'm looking forward to the time when there will be a new different answer to this SO question and the DX is improved :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. There's also `reload webviews` command somewhere, but not sure how to call it yet.

```
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(
      vscode.commands.registerCommand(REFRESH_COMMAND, () => {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.reloadWindow");
      })
    );
}

function watchForExtensionChanges() {
  const uiFolderPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"); // Replace with the actual path to your "src" directory
  console.log("Start watching uiFolderPath :>> ", uiFolderPath);
  fs.watch(uiFolderPath, { recursive: true }, (eventType, filename) => {
    console.log(`File ${filename} changed`, eventType);
    if (eventType === "change") {
      vscode.commands.executeCommand(REFRESH_COMMAND);
    }
  });
}
```